# Screen goes black as soon as I log in to access my Work on Citrix via icaclient

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, chromebook, citrix, icaclient

first question here.

All was well when I finally installed icaclient (which did not work on 12.04 (precise), but now does on 14.04 trusty). Suddenly, every time I log into my work via icaclient, as soon as I'm in, the screen goes completely black. I can't see the mouse cursor and the only way to get out is to force shut down.

I am on a Chromebook accessing Linux via crouton which has been great so far, but my main reason for installing Linux is citrix access (which does not work natively on a chromebook).

Has anyone come across a similar Citrix issue? Pls help :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, also crouton on a chromebook.

What made it work in the end was getting the version of the ica client that my particular CAG offered (v11.x rather than the most current v13.x in my case).

I had to then extract the tar.gz and install.

I had to use firefox with the older client, not chrome (chrome seemed ok with the v13 client).

I also had to do the 5th step shown at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CitrixICAClientHowTo

the first command deals with ICA client error 61, the second command deals with error 5.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is forcing Citrix NOT to use full screen. I have found this solution at the Arch linux forum, which solved it for me.

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=242398
https://discussions.citrix.com/topic/395450-unusable-after-upgrade-to-xorg-v120/#comment-2025832

Edit ~/.ICAClient/All_Regions.ini

```
[Virtual Channels\Seamless Windows]
TWIMode=0

[Virtual Channels\Thinwire Graphics]
DesiredColor=8
ApproximateColors=*
DesiredHRES=1024
DesiredVRES=768
ScreenPercent=*
UseFullScreen=false
TWIFullScreenMode=false
NoWindowManager=false
```